# Creating subdomain in Plesk with PHP

Tags: php, apache, plesk

I was creating subdomain on Plesk 12.5.30 version with api:
https://github.com/pmill/php-plesk

After filling up all data it brings error in plesk:
New configuration files for the Apache web server were not created due to the errors in configuration templates:

> Template processing failed: file =
>   /opt/psa/admin/conf/templates/default/domainVhost.php, error =
>   Template_Exception: Empty content was provided for config file
>   /var/www/vhosts/system/a22.ubicross.me/conf/httpd.conf file:
>   /opt/psa/admin/plib/Template/Writer/Webserver/Abstract.php line: 47
>   code: 0.
>
> Detailed error descriptions were sent to you by email. Please resolve
>   the issues and click here to generate broken configuration files once
>   again or here to generate all configuration files. See the details in
>   Configuration Troubleshooter

Can someone navigate me what is the issue I have tried all. Subdomain is creating without problem when you make it from admin but with script I got that issue.

Mention: Everything is set as it mentioned in php-plesk.

Thanks.

Comment: I suggest looking at [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com/) for this

Answer (score 0):

As error message said "See the details in Configuration Troubleshooter".

Also you can check /usr/local/psa/admin/log/panel.log